# Is it possible to open port in Azure Linux Web App

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

I have a framework which connects to Virtual Machine through the specific port. But I want to make WebApp Linux on Azure with this code.

I used image docker file where I exposed necessary port. If it’s enough to open the port?

[image]

By the way in Azure portal tab Networking is always grey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, web app on Linux does not support **Networking**. It is only supported by windows web app.

This is the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps) of web app, you could post your idea to help azure improve it.