# network restriction with app services for linux or docker OS Type

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I am using app services with windows OS type i get the option for setting IP restriction under Networking. But when I select Linux or Docker OS type the Network option is grayed out. Is this a limitation or do I need to select a specific plan I have not selected and hence this issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, **Networking** is now only supported by windows app service, app service on Linux and docker do not support it. No matter which plan you choose, the option is always unable.

Here is a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50681549/is-it-possible-to-open-port-in-azure-linux-web-app/50711619#50711619), you could refer to it. Also, if you want wo improve it, just post it in the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps).

**Workaround**:

If you want to set **IP restriction** for **Linux or Docker** App, I recommend you to use azure powershell to access it, just refer to the command below.

```
$r = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName "Resoucegroup name" -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName yourAppname/web -ApiVersion 2016-08-01

    $p = $r.Properties
    $p.ipSecurityRestrictions = @()
    $restriction = @{}
    $restriction.Add("ipAddress","0.0.0.0")
    $restriction.Add("subnetMask","0.0.0.0")
    $p.ipSecurityRestrictions+= $restriction

    Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName  "Resoucegroup name" -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName yourAppname/web -ApiVersion 2016-08-01 -PropertyObject $p
```

It works fine on my side(both Linux and Docker), you could check it in the **Resource Explorer**(you could access it in the azure portal).

[image]

[image]